# Multiple listViews with their own headers nestled in one view?

Tags: java, android, listview

This tutorial - http://andytsui.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/tutorial-displaying-multiple-lists-in-one-single-listview-with-android-binding/ - shows exactly what I want to do, but it uses an external library to accomplish it. I was hoping it would be possible to do it with the built in android utilities.

This is what I have now. >> https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwplv.png

foobar.zip, links.zip, and zips.zip come from the bootimg402 link, and I would like them displayed under that header, and the other zips under the other heading.

Headers are created with

```
        mURLURLS = new String[] {"http://rootzwiki.com/topic/12083-unsecured-stock-bootimg402/", "http://rootzwiki.com/topic/12451-rom-android-open-kang-project-toro-build-2012-dec-31/"};         
    for (int i=0; i<mURLURLS.length; i++) {
        getListView().addHeaderView(buildHeader(mURLURLS[i]));
    }

   private View buildHeader(String mURLURLS) {
    TextView header = new TextView(this);
    header.setText(mURLURLS);
    header.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dialog_full_holo_dark);
    header.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ics));
    return header;
   }
```

And the listview is populated through an ArrayList, which I can provide if needed, though I dont imagine its necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my [`MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) for that. Create views for your headers and interleave them between your adapters for the contents within those headers.

Comment: The example you provided uses the CWAC-SackOfViewsAdapter.jar external jar. If possible Im trying to avoid using non android utilities.

Comment: @r2DoesInc: `MergeAdapter` is one class (you don't need `MergeSpinnerAdapter` here). It depends on `SackOfViewsAdapter`, which is one class. Both are open source. Talented programmers reuse existing source code, directly where possible, or as a source of techniques where not.

Comment: Though not EXACTLY what I wanted, I got it to work. Was surprisingly easy. Wasnt trying to demean your code, I just prefer to rely on stock Android utilities where possible.